# Using FormsAuthentication on webMethod

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, webmethod

I have a page that has a comment section. This section communicates to a `WebMethod` in order to insert a new comment.

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool insertComment(string commentString)
{
    //userName validation here
    string userName = (FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name);

    return new CommentClass().InsertComment(commentString, userName);
}
```

The problem is: *"An object reference is required for the non-static field"*. 
I know I could send the information from a hidden field, or a `div`, however, that information field may be changed easily.
So which way could be used to know which user is posting, in server side? 
thanks a lot!

Comment: Is `Request` the object that needs a reference right?

Comment: Yes! sorry about that... that's the only part that requires reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Request` object is an instance that lives in `Page`, so you need a reference to access this object in a static context. You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request` for accessing the `Request` in this context.

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool insertComment(string commentString)
{
    //userName validation here
    string userName = 
           (FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(
               HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name);
    return new CommentClass().InsertComment(commentString, userName);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I'm going to try it. Thanks bro!